# How to sort an array by its index? (SortIndex)

Tags: java, arrays

I have a `long[]` with its values. The thing I need is to have a sorted array that contains the indices of my first array.

For example:

INPUT:

```
long[ ] values = {1 , 3 , 2 , 5 , 4};
```

OUTPUT:

```
long[ ] SortIndex = {0 , 2 , 1 , 4 , 3}
```

which means:

```
values[0] < values[2] < values[1] < values[4] < values[3]
```

...descending or ascending order of the `SortIndex` is not important.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To the right when you were asking your question there was a box titled "How to Format". Worth a read, as are the various things accessible via the **[?]** button above the text area, and this editing tips page: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help I've cleaned up the question for you this time 'round.

Comment: thank you so much for your editing

no, there is no guarantee that the values are unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another elegant solution by using the java `Comparator` interface. It also works when the values are not unique:

```
final Long[] values = { 1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 2};
Integer[] indices = new Integer[values.length];
for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
    indices[i] = i;
}
Comparator<Integer> comparator = new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer arg0, Integer arg1) {
        return values[arg0].compareTo(values[arg1]);
    }
};
Arrays.sort(indices, comparator);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(indices));
```

OUTPUT:

```
[0, 2, 5, 1, 4, 3]
```

- You can change the output order from ascending to descending by changing the compare order in the `compare()` method:

  ```
  public int compare(Integer arg0, Integer arg1) {
      return values[arg1].compareTo(values[arg0]);
  }
  ```
- You can also change the `Long[]` with any other comparable data type.

Answer (score 5):

```
long[] values = {1 , 3 , 2 , 5 , 4};
Map<Long, Integer> indices = new HashMap<Long, Integer>();
for (int index = 0; index < values.length; index++) {
    indices.put(values[index], index);
}

long[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(values, values.length);
Arrays.sort(copy);
for (int index = 0; index < copy.length; index++) {
    copy[index] = indices.get(copy[index]);
}
```

Your list of indices will be in `copy`.

Working example here:  http://ideone.com/A9Imz

Comment: this is true when your values are unique, I don't thing he has mentioned any such constraint.

Comment: Rather a simpler implementation could be to write your own sort algorithm, and while in the swapping step of values, swap the "sortedIndex" as well. 
http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/arrayexamples/mergeSort.shtml
if required, I can write the code on how to do it.

Comment: @prap19 - I wouldn't call that a "simpler" solution.  Certainly it would require more code than shown above, even if using a trivial/inefficient sorting algorithm.  But yes, that is the necessary approach if the solution needs to correctly handle duplicate values.

Comment: yes, by "simpler" I meant without using extra data structure like hashmap in your case? do we need that?

Answer (score 3):

You could do this by adding pairs of `Long` to a `TreeMap`, where the key is `values[index]` and the value is `index`.

traversing the map's `iterator` will yield the sortindex values.

**update**

Seeing that there is no accepted answer, here is the code resulting from following up the comments to this answer.

```
    long[] values = { 1 , 3 , 2 , 5 , 4 };
    int[]  output = new int[values.length];

    Map<Long, Integer> map = new TreeMap<Long, Integer>();

    for (int n = 0; n < values.length; n++) {
        map.put(values[n] * values.length + n, n);
    }

    int n = 0;

    for (Integer index: map.values()) {
        output[n++] = index;
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output));
```

Output:

```
[0, 2, 1, 4, 3]
```

the solution also works when duplicates are part of the input:

```
long[] values = { 8, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1 };
```

Output:

```
[4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

If it is permissible to receive the `sortOrder` array as an `Integer` array, the second loop can be replaced by:

```
Integer[] output = map.values().toArray(new Integer[values.length]);
```

Comment: @prap19, the TreeMap will sort it's keys in natural order, iterating over the map (map.entrySet().iterator()) will give you the sorted values as keys and their original indexes as values.

Comment: SortIndex[] is the array of indexes different from natural index of the numbers in the values[] array. Can you still map the values to the index that it pointed to before sorting?

Comment: @prap19, of course - if the map would change the key-value pairs it wouldn't be a map :-) while itarating the map you just store its values in the `sortIndex` array which is your output.

Comment: @AKJ, if values are not unique, you can make their map keys unique by using `values[index] * values.length + index` as key :-)

Answer (score 1):

One simplistic idea is to find the index of minimum value in each iteration and then put a large value in that index. This will work even if there are duplicates.
eg:

```
long[] values = { 1, 3, 2, 5, 4 };

long[] indices = new long[values.length];
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    long min = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    int minIndex = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
        if (min > values[j]) {
            minIndex = j;
            min = values[j];
        }
    }
    values[minIndex] = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    indices[i] = minIndex;
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(indices));
```

Answer (score 0):

The most direct least complex solution would be to include an index value in the sorted objects themselves, then just populate the augmented Long object with both the long values and the original array index values, then sort. As a bonus now you have both the original long values and the indices in the same object array. You might not need to use long[] arrays at all, but only use the augmented Long classes for all long array operations.

```
public class LongSort implements Comparable<LongSort> {
    public Long value;
    public int index;
    @Override public int compareTo(LongSort o) {
        return this.value.compareTo(o.value);
    }
}

long[] values = {1 , 3 , 2 , 5 , 4};
LongSort[] sortvalues = new LongSort[values.length];
for (int i=0;i<values.length;i++) {
    sortvalues[i].value = values[i];
    sortvalues[i].index = i;
}
Arrays.sort(sortvalues);
```

Another fully generic version of the comparator index sorter, that supports custom comparators:

```
public static class ObjectSort<T> implements Comparator<Integer> {
    private Comparable<T>[] data;
    private Comparator<T> comp;
    public ObjectSort(Comparable<T>[] datai, Comparator<T> compi) {this.data=datai;this.comp=compi;}
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        int compval = -1;
        if (this.comp!=null) {
            compval = this.comp.compare((T)data[o1],(T)data[o2]);
        } else {
            compval = data[o1].compareTo((T)data[o2]);
        }
        return compval;
    }
}
public static <T> Integer[] objectIndexSort(Comparable<T>[] data, Comparator<T> comp) {
    Integer[] k = null;
    if ((data!=null)&&(data.length>0)) {
        Integer[] indices = new Integer[data.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
            indices[i] = i;
        }
        ObjectSort<T> comparator = new ObjectSort<T>(data, comp);
        Arrays.sort(indices, comparator);
        k = indices;
    }
    return k;
}
```